# How Jquery tag "insertAfter" display only once if element exist no repeat again and again?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please suggest to me an answer for my question: how Jquery tag "insertAfter" display only once if element exist no repeat again and again?

```
$(document).ready(function (){$(".ddd").keypress(function (e) {

 if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
    $("<span style='color:red'>insert only character</span>").insertAfter( $(this)).show().fadeOut("slow");   
     return false;
}
 });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery's [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property on your selector to check if it exists. If it doesn't, insert it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".ddd").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {

      if (!$("#err").length)
        $("<span id= 'err' style='color:red'>insert only character</span>").insertAfter($(e.target));

      $("#err").show().fadeOut("slow");
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="ddd"></input>
```

Comment: in my form there are multiple text box and this onkeypress event tigger in multiple text boxses if i using id showing error mes in only one position where very first event is tiggered